# curl is not installed on this server error in wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, curl

I have added twitter feed plugin and feel up all thing which were required. But there was an error like

```
curl is not installed on this server
```

I had done these steps :

1. Close WAMP (if running)
2. Navigate to WAMP\bin\php(your version of php)\
3. Edit php.ini
4. Search for curl, uncomment extension=php_curl.dll
5. Navigate to WAMP\bin\Apache(your version of apache)\bin\
6. edit php.ini
7. Search for curl, uncomment extension=php_curl.dll
8. Save both
   9 .Restart WAMP

But still I received this error. So What should i have to do to resolve this issue?

Comment: you can use phpinfo() function and find curl and if curl is enable or not?
what is your OS ubuntu or windows?

Comment: its windows 7. it works on localhost but not in online.

Comment: Online means are you working in live server..? you need to create sample file with contain of <?php echo phpinfo(); ?> and check it curl is enable or not?

Comment: yes i am working in live server.and where i have to put this code?

Comment: you need put any where in your live server for example /root directory/test.php and test.php file will contain <?php echo phpinfo(); ?> and you just execute this file like www.example.com/test.php.

Comment: it will display many things. for curl it will display " cURL : Sterling Hughes " like this.

Comment: I think this link will help you a lot.. https://github.com/Znote/ZnoteAAC/issues/122